# jquery not working on my device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this jquery code and html it is working on jsfiddle.com(http://jsfiddle.net/9rJev/) and this is the working example but when i get it to notepad++ its not working, and this is my code on notepad++

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.3.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#movedown').ready(function(){
    `$('#test').slideUp();`
})
$('#movedown').mouseover(function() {
$('#test').slideDown();
});
$('#movedown').mouseleave(function(){
 $('#test').slideUp();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="movedown">
    <h4>yazan</h4>
    <div id="test" style="background-color:lightgrey; border:2px solid grey;padding:10px;">Hello, this will slide down.</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

but its not working on google chrome anyone have any idea what is the issu.
please help.and thanks

Comment: You've included the jQuery library three times (v1.3.2, v1.6.4 AND v1.10.2). Try removing two of them.

Comment: any reason to include **3** jquery versions???

Comment: Why are you loading _three_ different versions of jQuery? Remove the first two, and make sure you load only the most jQuery version, and load it first

Comment: 3 copies of jQuery AND no `$(document).ready`.

Comment: And btw, there is no ready event for jq object other than wrapped document. Pseudo ready event propagate to document level so it is not really behaviour you are expecting... Even $().ready is valid, it is just not really how to use ready handler. And i don't talk about typo **`**.  Please improve your question...

Comment: This might give you a nudge in the right direction. http://jsfiddle.net/brightpixel/Gs2sr/

Comment: i have removed 2 include of the jquery and still is not working it just do the `.ready()` and the others does not work and idea(it is my first question sorry for this bad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JS to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#movedown').ready(function(){
        $('#test').slideUp();
    })
    $('#movedown').mouseover(function() {
        $('#test').slideDown();
    });
    $('#movedown').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#test').slideUp();
    });
});
```

And also remove all but 1 jquery reference. Note you need to include the ready function, and you had some odd characters around $('#test').slideUp(); which caused JS errors. After these minor changes your code performed fine for me.